# How to kill off a pending APM operation

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

If you have a pending operation, eg

```
stream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, _asyncCallbackRead, this);
```

and you close the stream provider, eg

```
serialPort.Close();
```

you unsurprisingly cause an exception.

Is there an preferred method by which one might cancel a pending APM operation, prior to closing the port?

---

## The world has changed

Use `IStream.ReadAsync(Memory<Byte>, CancellationToken)`

---

Colby's reply is not the answer I hoped for, but he does at least close off a fruitless avenue in inquiry.

Happily I have found a solution.

> As noted by a commenter, this will probably leak but as I do this *because* the app is trying to exit, it hardly matters. You should use a cancellation token anyway.

For each stream I maintain various state information in a class `DeviceSession`. This class has a method `ReadStream` providing the implementation for the `AsyncCallback` that handles incoming data.

Note that `_asyncCallbackRead` and every other variable beginning with an underscore is a class private member assigned in the constructor of DeviceSession.

The constructor also provides the initial call to `_stream.BeginRead`.

```
void ReadStream(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  if (IsOpen) 
    try
    {
      DevicePacket packet;
      int cbRead = _stream.EndRead(ar);
      _endOfValidData += cbRead;
      while ((packet = GetPacket()) != null)
        CommandStrategy.Process(this, packet);
      _stream.BeginRead(_buffer, _endOfValidData, 
        _buffer.Length - _endOfValidData, 
        _asyncCallbackRead, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
      Trace.TraceError("{0}\r\n{1}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
      _restart(_streamProvider, _deviceId);
    }
}
```

Notice that I haven't bothered to set `ar.AsyncState`. Because the callback delegate refers to the method of a specific instance of DeviceSession, detailed and strongly typed context information (contained in the members of this instance of DeviceSession) is *automatically* in scope. This is the point of having a session object.

Back on the subject of aborting a listener, closing the stream provider triggers the callback but attempting to invoke EndRead results in an `IOException`.

Generally such an exception indicates a fault requiring a listener restart and one will want to respond by restarting the stream provider and recreating the session. This is complicated by the absence of a reliable stream-provider-independent way to determine whether the provider has faulted or the user is trying to restart the connection (eg plugged a new device into the port).

The trick is to add more context (`IsOpen`) to the `DeviceSession` to indicate whether the session is open or has been closed, and use it to smoothly complete the final abortive execution of `ReadStream`.

If `IsOpen` is `true` then an `IOException` represents a failure in need of recovery. If `IsOpen` is `false` the failure was deliberately induced and no action is required.

Comment: I'm going to note that your "solution" is a resource leak.  According to the documentation, you are required to call `EndRead` to let it cleanup.  Even if you know it's going to throw, it still has to be called.

Comment: (Note also that this is why when you provide your own answer, you should write an answer and not edit it into the question)

Comment: While there is some truth to this, usually when my code kills a pending listener it's because the application is exiting and memory leakage has ceased to matter. The need to call EndRead and handle the exception is interesting. According to which doc? I'd like to read it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not directly supported in the framework. Your best bet is to write a wrapper that spawns a thread and use synchronization primitives like events to signal a cancel request.

HTH

Colby Africa

Answer (score 3):

*[Inspired by the chapter on APM in Richter's CLR via C# I decided to see what goodies SO had on the subject and I found this question.  I thought Peter had a great question here and did a bit of research -- this is the result]*

Jeffrey Richter in CLR via C# (chapter 27) discusses his AsyncEnumerator class which (supposedly) takes much of the pain away from programming the APM.  One of the features of this class (part of his freely available [Power Threading Libary](https://github.com/Wintellect/PowerThreading)) is the ability to cancel asynchronous operations.

The class can be downloaded from the link above.  The page also includes a link to a Yahoo Group Richter set up to provided limited support for the lib.

He introduces the library in these MSDN articles:

[Simplified APM With The AsyncEnumerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc546608.aspx)
[More AsyncEnumerator Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721613.aspx#id0390081)