# COM port is denied

Tags: c#, serial-port

Hi I am trying to use COM port to read some registers using modbus protocol, everything works fine until I rebote modbus slave device, then I have error that com is denied, what I can do is or rebot computer or plug out and back in 'usb to com converter'. Seems that this device doesn't handle with com port properly.

```
using (port = new SerialPort(comPort))
{
   ushort[] registers = null;
   try
   {
      port.BaudRate = boudRate;
      port.DataBits = 8;
      port.Parity = Parity.None;
      port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
      port.Open();

      // modbus reading registers

      port.Close();
      return registers;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      Logs.AddToLog(e.Message);
      return registers;
   }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get (and where do you get it)?

Comment: it works preety well, but when i rebot my modbus slave, and try to read again then i have exception that this COM port is denied

Comment: You have it wrapped in a `using` statement, so the port should be closed, but you might want to check .IsOpen just to make sure: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.isopen.aspx

Comment: i did it, IsOpen is fals, and when i try to open i have exceptin that COM port is denied

Comment: I also noticed that the using statement doesnt have `SerialPort port` in it.  You wont be able to use `port` outside of this as it will be disposed.  Does it work if you change it to `using (SerialPort port = ...`

Comment: How quickly after closing it are you trying to open it again?

Comment: doens't matter , one minute, still the same, unitil i will rebote computer or diconect converter

Comment: You mention a USB to Serial adapter. Are you using an adapter that uses the FTDI chipset, or the Prolific chipset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using an FTDI USB/Serial adapter, you can retrieve the state directly from the managed wrapper ([FTDI Managed Driver Wrapper](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp/FTD2XX_NET_1010.zip)) and reinitialize your serial port based on the connected state.

Forgive my lack of experiance with FTDI devices, but this should reset your R-232 adapter:

```
FTD2XX_NET.FTDI device = new FTD2XX_NET.FTDI();
string port;
device.GetCOMPort(out port);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(port) && (port.Equals(target)) && device.IsOpen)
{
    device.CyclePort();
    device.ResetDevice();
    device.ResetPort();
}
```

By my understanding `device.CyclePort()` will close any active connection (calls `FT_CLOSE`), unmounts the usb device, and reenumerates the device from the usb bus. This should be exactly the same as if you physically removed, and reinserted the adapter.

Also, according to the documentation for the Perl wrapper for the FTDI device library:

> As with other bus controls, there is a
>   wait period of 5-8 seconds after   a
>   CyclePort where any API call that
>   requires direct connection to the
>   device,    like GetSerialByIndex()
>   etc, will fail with FT_INVALID_HANDLE
>   until it has    completely stabilized.
>   The application should account for
>   this wait period, or   setup a polling
>   loop to detect the change in return
>   status.

Comment: ok and how can i use these dll in my case to prevent this error?

Comment: even this doesn't help:                     FTDI myFtdiDevice = new FTDI();
                    myFtdiDevice.CyclePort();
                    myFtdiDevice.ResetDevice();
                    myFtdiDevice.ResetPort();
                    myFtdiDevice.RestartInTask();
                    myFtdiDevice.Rescan();
                    myFtdiDevice.Close();

Comment: nooo, firs what is target? second , i checked many times before, ifIsOpen, is not open , but when i try to open got exception that is denied, so i even put true in this 'if' statetmant and still after can't open port, but when i reset the converter, plug out and back in, then it works.

Comment: `target` is the name of the comm port you are having problems with. This is just a simple check to make sure your not trying to use the FTDI driver with a non FTDI device.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar experience where an FTDI device would enter a state where I couldn't communicate with it unless I physically unplugged it.  Greg's answer helped me come up with a workaround.

Greg's reference to FTDI's managed wrapper was very helpful, but the snippet he provided isn't quite there because it takes a bit more code to actually reference an FTDI device.  With his idea as a starting point, I adapted some example code from FTDI and wrote this function.  It was able to put my FTDI device back into a working state without physical intervention.

```
/// <summary>
/// Attempts to reset an attached FTDI device and returns true if successful.  Note that a
/// 5-8 second delay is recommended after the reset.
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool ResetFTDI() {
  UInt32 ftdiDeviceCount = 0;
  FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_STATUS ftStatus = FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK;

  // Create new instance of the FTDI device class
  FTD2XX_NET.FTDI myFtdiDevice = new FTD2XX_NET.FTDI();
  // Determine the number of FTDI devices connected to the machine
  ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetNumberOfDevices(ref ftdiDeviceCount);
  // Check status
  if (ftStatus != FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK) {
    Log.WriteLog("Failed to get number of FTDI devices [" + ftStatus.ToString() + "]");
    return false;
  }
  // If no devices available, return
  if (ftdiDeviceCount == 0) {
    Log.WriteLog("Failed to find any FTDI devices [" + ftStatus.ToString() + "]");
    return false;
  }
  // Allocate storage for device info list
  FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[] ftdiDeviceList = new FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_DEVICE_INFO_NODE[ftdiDeviceCount];
  // Populate our device list
  ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.GetDeviceList(ftdiDeviceList);
  if (ftStatus != FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK) {
    Log.WriteLog("Failed enumerate FTDI devices [" + ftStatus.ToString() + "]");
    return false;
  }
  // Open first device in our list by serial number
  ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.OpenBySerialNumber(ftdiDeviceList[0].SerialNumber);
  if (ftStatus != FTD2XX_NET.FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK) {
    Log.WriteLog("Failed to open device [" + ftStatus.ToString() + "]");
    return false;
  }
  // Finally, reset the port
  myFtdiDevice.CyclePort();
  return true;
}
```

The Log object above is internal to my project so substitute whatever suits you.

Some further research also turned up [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441559/how-to-do-robust-serialport-programming-with-net-c).  In the answers, Zach Saw references a problem he discovered with .NET SerialPort communications.  I'm going to try his solution and I'll post back here if that resolves the problem entirely because I consider the above to be something of a bandaid.